# C++ how to declare bitwise operators for different types of flags?

Tags: c++, enums

First, my flags set is an `enum` like this:

```c
typedef enum
{
    F0 = 0,
    F1 = 1,
    F2 = 2,
    F3 = 4
} Flags1;
```

In C I can do any bitwise operations on them, but not in C++.

So I have the macro:

```c
#define BIT_FLAG_OPERATORS(flags)\
inline flags operator ~(flags a) { return static_cast<flags>(~static_cast<int>(a)); }\
inline flags operator &(flags a, flags b) { return static_cast<flags>(static_cast<int>(a) & static_cast<int>(b)); }\
inline flags& operator &=(flags& a, flags b) { return a = a & b; }\
inline flags operator |(flags a, flags b) { return static_cast<flags>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b)); }\
inline flags& operator |=(flags& a, flags b) { return a = a | b; }\
inline flags operator ^(flags a, flags b) { return static_cast<flags>(static_cast<int>(a) ^ static_cast<int>(b)); }\
inline flags& operator ^=(flags& a, flags b) { return a = a ^ b; }
```

...and I use it like this:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
BIT_FLAG_OPERATORS(Flags1);
#endif
```

Works.

Then I make another set of flags:

```c
typedef enum
{
    F20 = 0,
    F21 = 1,
    F22 = 2,
    F23 = 4
} Flags2;
```

...and use the macro:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
BIT_FLAG_OPERATORS(Flags2);
#endif
```

...and it doesn't work, I get "conflicting declaration of C function `Flags2 operator...`".

Why is that and how should I change my macro to be able to apply it for different flags types?

It would be best if it was somehow possible to apply it to ALL `enums`, so, somehow define the operators for all enum types, not for each type separately. But how?

**EDIT:**

I got it:
Where my header is included, there is indeed `extern "C" {`. My header file is included in many places, I just missed that one and was sure there is no `extern "C" {`. But it was. Thanks to suggestions in comments I found it. That was it.

Comment: The shown code does not produce that error. Are you trying to write this in a `extern "C"` block? If so: Of course it makes no sense to put operator overloads there. They are a C++ feature.

Comment: @user17732522: No, it's code not in `extern "C"` block, however it's compiled both by C and C++ compiler. I forgot to mention I have `#ifdef __cplusplus` around calling my macro.

Comment: @Harry Then I don't see how this is supposed to generate that error message (after fixing the typo mentioned above). Please provide a complete [mre], including the compiler used.

Comment: Note that the negation in particular will cause undefined behavior when used since it produces a result outside the range of the enumeration. I am not sure why you are trying to define that specifically.

Comment: @user17732522: Negation is used to clear bits and it works. I don't use negation directly, I rather use something like `x &= ~flag`. As for the example - "no can't do", a part of a complicated STM32 project, I suspect that taken away from the context it could work. Anyway, when I use the macro the first time, no error, 2 times - error occurs when the macro is used the second time.

Comment: The `static_cast<flags>` done for the return value in `operator~` already has undefined behavior, no matter what argument you give it. Before the cast some of the higher `int` bits will be set. The standard defines the range of an unscoped enumeration without explicit underlying type as zero to the maximum enumerator value, rounded up to the next power of two. The value after `~` will exceed that and so the `static_cast` will have undefined behavior.

Comment: As for the example: If you can't produce one, then there is nothing we can do but close the question as non-reproducible. It _does_ compile the way you presented it. The problem is in code you are not showing.

Comment: @user17732522: Then how should I properly clear bits in my value?

Comment: `conflicting declaration of C function` means your functions **are** in an `extern "C"` block. There is no other way for this message to be produced.

Comment: @Harry You can clear the bits individually. Obviously that is not a nice solution, but without more information I am not sure what alternative to suggest. Do you need the enumeration type to be usable on the C side as well? Do you need this to be strongly-typed? If e.g. both answers are "no", then just use `constexpr int` constants instead of the enumeration and use normal airthmetical built-in operators.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KhYseYfWj).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That's the most relevant hint here. The problem is I don't see it. Yet. It's STM32 project in STM32CubeIDE. It uses both C and C++ compilers. This is a content of a ".h" file. But it is included in a ".hpp" file.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I GOT IT! Thanks, you're an MVP!

Comment: You can apply these functions to all enums by making them templates, but do you really want to? They would also work on enums that were never intended to be bit flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is that what you have already works.  It's debatable whether it's a good idea to convert back to an enum, but if that's what you want, then there's nothing wrong with the code you show and it was just another bug, so you might consider deleting the question.

Here's a slightly cleaner working example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

enum Flags1 {
    F0 = 0,
    F1 = 1,
    F2 = 2,
    F3 = 4
};

enum Flags2 {
    F20 = 0,
    F21 = 1,
    F22 = 2,
    F23 = 4
};

#define BIT_BINARY_OP(Type, Op)                 \
inline Type                                     \
operator Op(Type a, Type b)                     \
{                                               \
  return Type(int(a) Op int(b));                \
}                                               \
inline Type&                                    \
operator Op##=(Type &a, Type b)                 \
{                                               \
  return a = Type(a Op b);                      \
}

#define BIT_FLAG_OPERATORS(flags)                               \
inline flags operator~(flags a) { return flags(~int(a)); }      \
BIT_BINARY_OP(flags, &)                                         \
BIT_BINARY_OP(flags, ^)                                         \
BIT_BINARY_OP(flags, |)

BIT_FLAG_OPERATORS(Flags1);
BIT_FLAG_OPERATORS(Flags2);

int
main()
{
  auto f1 = F1|F2;
  f1 |= F3;
  [[maybe_unused]] auto f2 = ~(F20|F21);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f1), Flags1>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f2), Flags2>);
}
```

Comment: He probably means the conversion back to a `Flags1` after arithmetic, which doesn't work implicitly.

Comment: Yeah, except the bitwise or of two flags won't in general be a flag.  So maybe some broader context is missing here?

Comment: Yes, some of these operations in the question make no sense to begin with, e.g. negation. (And also cause undefined behavior)

Comment: No, it doesn't work in C++. I get `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'MyFlags' [-fpermissive]` when I try to do any bitwise operations between `MyFlags` and `MyFlags` type. That's the whole point, the code worked as C, now I moved the portion to the C++ file and I get errors.